# How do I export Outlook.com emails to Google Apps?

Tags: google-workspace, outlook.com, migrate-data

I migrated from Outlook.com for company emails to Google Apps.

How can I get the old emails on my Outlook.com to Google Apps email?

Comment: Google (the search engine) [is your friend](http://www.viwoinc.com/2013/01/how-to-migrate-off-microsoft-office-365/)

Comment: I only asked because I couldn't find any definitive answer on google.

Comment: OK, if you edit your question to include what you have tried and how it failed, it will be easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is follow the same process as you would to [Centralize mail from different accounts with Mail Fetcher](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289). This will allow you to connect to your old Outlook.com account and download the emails you have there into your new Gmail account.

You'll need to use the following:

- Incoming mail server: pop3.live.com
- User Name: your outlook.com email address
- Password: your outlook.com password
- Incoming mail server port: 995 (SSL required)

If you only want to import existing messages, you can disable Mail Fetcher after the initial import.

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution is to use the Google Apps Migration Tool for Microsoft Exchange.

Despite the name, it also works with IMAP services.

https://tools.google.com/dlpage/exchangemigration

It will pull the messages and folders (including the sent items). It can also do multiple accounts at one time.

If you use Mail Fetcher, you will not get the sent items.